# git merge conflict: we uploaded the same image!

Tags: git

I am new to Git and this is the first time I have experienced a merge conflict. I replaced an image, ran `git commit` and all was good. What I didn't realize was that a co-worker had done the same thing and commited their change to the remote repository. Then I ran `git svn rebase` (since we're using subversion) and I got myself into a state of conflict.

How can I simply "undo" my commit all together and accept the incoming changes?

### Solution

Since I had already committed my change to my local repository, I needed to reset to the commit prior to my latest commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Now I am able to get the latest changes from remote:

```
git svn rebase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your commit is your last commit, you can just use `git reset --hard <commit>` to reset your repo to the commit before yours. Then just run `git svn rebase` again. You may also need to run `get rebase --abort` to get out of the current svn rebase operation.

Comment: so I did `git reset --hard HEAD`. `git status` showed that I was clean, but not on a branch. So I switched back to master branch. `git status` also shows clean. But when I do `git log` my commit is still there. What is going to happen when I run `git svn dcommit`?

Comment: You need to reset --hard to a commit before your commit adding the image. Perhaps `git reset --hard HEAD^`?

Comment: yes! that worked. thank you. I was then able to `git svn rebase` without any issues.